# How to determine page type when web crawling domains with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-crawler, webrequest

I am trying to see if there is a concrete way to determine what a page type or extension is of a home url. For an example, if I do a web request to a domain such as www.example.com, is the page it is returning a .PHP or .ASP extension type. I would like to try to scan all domains in a range, and return only .asp classic pages and sits as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you cannot determine how the server responds to a URL request. Assuming you cannot look at the extension (as in the case you describe), the response headers may be helpful. For example:

1. Look at `X-AspNet-Version`. If the latter is present, it is almost certainly IIS running ASP.NET. If that fails, look for at the `Server` header, which may be something like "Microsoft-IIS/8.0"
2. Look at `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`. If this is absent or set to just GET and POST on IIS (see above point), it is likely to be classic ASP or ASP.NET.
3. Some websites may contain specialist headers. For example, blog sites may contain the header `X-Pingback` which may point to a URL with an extension.

Another option is to use white hat hacking tools. I know [nmap can remotely determine the OS](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html) but not necessarily how a page was generated. However, I would not recommend this without prior permission from the websites as it could be considered an attack.

Let me take a step back. Why do you want to determine whether they are running ASP? If you are looking for a vulnerability, to exploit, refer the question to a security forum. If you are a control writer and want to see whether people are pirating your tools, embed a piece of distinct HTML in the control output that you can scan for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yea, I can't use external tools due to some other issues I need to resolve in the application, but I do like your advice on "using unique code to scan for".  I didn't think there was a way, but I don't ever assume I know an answer 100%. Just checking that I didn't overlook something. Thanks again.